# Can I measure the CPU usage in Linux by thread into application

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

I have the multi-threading C application (daemon). Can I measure the CPU usage by thread into my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is an old question it came up as the top related hit on my own Google search. So I'll provide the answer I came up with.

Assuming you're using pthreads or a library that uses it, such as Boost libraries.

You can use `pthread_getcpuclockid` and `clock_gettime`.
Man page links [pthread_getcpuclockid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getcpuclockid.3.html), [clock_gettime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

Here is a simple example that return the current time as a *double*.

```
double cpuNow( void ) {
    struct timespec ts;
    clockid_t cid;

    pthread_getcpuclockid(pthread_self(), &cid);
    clock_gettime(cid, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec + (((double)ts.tv_nsec)*0.000000001);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out the data from  `/proc/<PID>/stat`. The CPU line looks like this:-

```
cpu  143359 8217 480152 132054567 45162 5678 24656 0 0
```

Comment: I have one process and one pid and many threads. Each thread get incoming connections and make a work. I develope the monitoring by threads and interesting information for me "How the thead is loading"